# PHP Array to string conversion error

Tags: php

I am trying to output some content from my DB table, i successfully made a query and also return controller code but when i am trying ouput it in my view, what i tried

```
 <tr>
            <?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
            <td>
     <pre>
            <?php
            var_dump($products[$product['product_id']]['manufacturers']);

                   foreach ($products[$product['product_id']]['manufacturers'] as $manufacturer) { 
                    echo $manufacturer;
                   } ?>
            </pre>
            </td>
            <?php } ?>
          </tr>
```

> **ERROR**
>
> Notice: Array to string conversion in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\usa\catalog\view\theme\usadevims\template\product\compare.tpl
>   on line 72ArrayNotice: Array to string conversion in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\usa\catalog\view\theme\usadevims\template\product\compare.tpl
>   on line 72ArrayNotice: Array to string conversion in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\usa\catalog\view\theme\usadevims\template\product\compare.tpl
>   on line 72Array

and here the var_dump of my variable

```
array(3) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        ["name"]=>
        string(5) "Apple"
        ["manufacturer_id"]=>
        string(1) "8"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(2) {
        ["name"]=>
        string(3) "HTC"
        ["manufacturer_id"]=>
        string(1) "5"
      }
      [2]=>
      array(2) {
        ["name"]=>
        string(4) "Sony"
        ["manufacturer_id"]=>
        string(2) "10"
      }
    }
```

Comment: it is $products array or $product array?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$manufacturer references to an array. Try:

```
echo $manufacturer['name'];
```

or

```
echo $manufacturer['manufacturer_id];
```

As you can see on your `var_dump`, your variable `$products[$product['product_id']]['manufacturers']` is an array composed by three other arrays. So each iteration of your loop will assign an array to $manufacturer variable.